# Moon+ Reader Pro TTS

Tags: text-to-speech, moon-reader

I know that there is a TTS ability in MOON+ Reader Pro.
Can someone explain me exactly how I can TTS a ebook with MOON+ Reader Pro. 
I don't see any option or speak button.

regards

Comment: Have you tried this: *Shake the phone to speak (Text-to-speech, TTS engine support)* [source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp)

Answer (score 1):

You find it in the options, in the "control" section. If you tap on an action (e.g. for "shake"), a drop-down opens where you can select many things -- a.o. *Read (Text-to-Speech)*. If you enable it here and then shake the device, Moon+ will start to read the text to you. Shake again to make it stop.

You also can assign it to your DPad keys, or the headset controls (just scroll further down on that page to see for yourself).

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to fully disable the shake feature. This is very annoying when running and using TTS. :|

Comment: It no longer fires for me (I had that issue as well originally). I don't remember exactly what I disabled for that, but I don't use TTS in Moon+ at all – so I definitely disabled all relevant stuff in this app.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this: At the bottom of *Miscellaneous Options* page, there's an option *Customize Reader Bar Icon*. Tap it and check *Speak*.

Now, you can easily access TTS from bottom bar.